# Google Script formatDate

Tags: google-apps-script, formatdatetime

I don't understand how does it work Utilities.formatDate(). I have script:

```
var A=new Date();
var B=Utilities.formatDate( A, SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "YY.MM.dd HH:mm");
```

This has been working for months, but today (dec 31.) is problem... 
A=Tue Dec 31 2019 15:24:18 GMT+0100 (CET)
B="2020.12.31 15:24"
This is bug? How to fix a bug?
I try yesterday date:

```
var A=new Date(new Date()-(1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

but formatDate return: "20.12.30 15:24"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this `"YY.MM.dd HH:mm"` to `"yy.MM.dd HH:mm"`

```
function tdate() {
  var A=new Date(new Date()-(1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(A,Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"yy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss"));
  //[19-12-31 13:44:34:975 MST] 19.12.30 13:44:34
  Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(A,SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"yy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss"));
  //[19-12-31 13:51:07:677 MST] 19.12.30 13:51:07
  Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(A,Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"YY.MM.dd HH:mm:ss"));
  //[19-12-31 13:44:34:976 MST] 20.12.30 13:44:34
  Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(A,SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"YY.MM.dd HH:mm:ss"));
  //[19-12-31 13:51:07:678 MST] 20.12.30 13:51:07

}
```

[Simple Date Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)