# Google Apps Script year bug

Tags: google-apps-script

I just ran into an awkward issue on Google Apps Script.

Since yesterday, Dec 30, 2019, the function `Utilities.formatDate` returns 2020 as the current year.
In the screenshot, you can see the log of the function `yearBug`.
The log timestamp clearly indicates Dec 31, 2019, but the output is 2020.

[image]

The timezone in the code and in the log is EST (Toronto time).

Does anyone have a good explanation?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59545685/google-script-formatdate/59548310#59548310

Comment: good question, i also suffered with this issue last half month :>

Comment: @Igal Roytblat Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 1):

From your script which can be seen in your shared image, I thought that the reason of your issue might be `YYYY` of `MMMM d, YYYY`. `Y` is used as the Week year. So please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "America/Toronto", "MMMM d, YYYY"));
```

#### To:

```
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "America/Toronto", "MMMM d, yyyy"));
```

#### References :

- [formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)
- [Date and Time Patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

  > - `y`: Year
  > - `Y`: Week year

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for kind reply, i also solve this issue from your answer <3

Comment: @ChangWon Jeong Juicycool Thank you for your comment. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.